# What is the meaning of しちまおう?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, conjugations

I'm playing a video game and in this scene the character is on a hill and says:

> このまま昼寝しちまおうか

My guess is that it's a conjugation of する but it doesn't look close to する at all.

What conjugations are present in that word and how does it affect the sentence's overall meaning?

Comment: 〜て＋しまう　→　〜ちまう　→　〜ちゃう

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like snailplane commented, it is a contracted form of して しまう.
I would add that the final ～おう marks the volitional form of しまう.
If that can help you understand better the sentence, an other very similar way of saying it would be:

> このまま昼ねを して しまいましょう か